connect to console only of VM created by virt-manager?
I have perfectly working ubuntu 24.04 VM running. My host machine is ubuntu 24.04 as well. I made my vm using virt-manager, which launches a full desktop GUI.
But I want to connect to it's console only without the GUI. I found out you can connect with using virsh. I have added console with add hardware in virt-manager machine details.
When I run virsh list --all I can see my VM. Afterwards I virsh start ubuntu24.04 and virsh console 24.04.
This brings up the following menu:
Connected to domain 'ubuntu24.04' 
Escape character is ^] (Ctrl + ])

I tried pressing enter and writing my crypt0 password and press enter. And none seemed to work.
Anyone knows how to get in the console from my terminal?
